# Authentication in HTML5 + phonegap application

Tags: html, cordova

I'm building an application on HTML5 + Jquery and REST services at back-end . This application is meant for Desktop users and mobile users. So we are building the mobile version using phonegap. this application is a secure application and needs login screen. but now am in fix how I can achieve this. 
1. If i Move the application to ASP.Net MVC then I can't create build using phonegap. 
2. For phonegap i found http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/11/10/Example-of-serverbased-login-with-PhoneGap but i think this is not suitable solution for desktop users

Answer (score 2):

You can secure the server side using the authentication technology of your choice and then make your AJAX calls to the rest services pass along the credentials.

For example, if you wanted to write your service using ASP.NET MVC, you could protect that using something as simple as HTTP Basic Auth and then pass along a user/pass string in your request.

To achieve the login screen, you can write a dummy controller method which your login screen can call just to check if the authentication is working.

If you want a sample ASP.NET MVC backend with a PhoneGap front-end using jQuery, then I have some sample code up on [GitHub](https://github.com/red-gate/nomad-crm-sample) and a [blog](http://vsnomad.com/tag/dtw-crm-sample/) describing building the application

Comment: If you use usual authentication technology, wouldn't the session/cookies be vulnerable to other local apps? I mean, as the app is stored locally, the domain is the local domain right? So if I run another app locally, would all the info about the session be available to it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean @CaioOliveira. Each app on the mobile device is isolated from the others by the sandbox on the device. If an app has the right privileges and the credentials are stored insecurely on the SD card or somewhere, then that app can read them. However, that is true for any data stored insecurely on the device.